# Black screen coming up in WkWebView while opening Camera Swift5

Tags: ios, swift, camera, wkwebview

[image]I have implemented WKWebView in iOS app. I have done some configuration for webview.

```
   public static var configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration {
     let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
     config.websiteDataStore = self.webCookieDataStore
     config.processPool = self.webProcessPool
     config.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = false
     return config
}
```

Videos are playing well in full screen and autoplay. But when I open camera in webview then black blank screen is appearing. Screenshot is from simulator for result purpose. The same thing is happening in iOS device.

Comment: Have you added the permission for accessing Camera?

Comment: Yes. If I change  config.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true, then it will work fine but i am facing error in iPad with full screen and autoplay in wkwebview

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this method ?

```
extension ViewController: WKUIDelegate {
    @available(iOS 15.0, *)
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decideMediaCapturePermissionsFor origin: WKSecurityOrigin, initiatedBy frame: WKFrameInfo, type: WKMediaCaptureType) async -> WKPermissionDecision {
        origin.host == BASE_URL .grant : .deny
    }
}
```

Reference :
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10032/ (16:26)